# how to have one array value, find a value in another array?

Tags: php, arrays, match

if i have the following two arrays im PHP:

First array ($array1):

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["movie_id"]=>
    int(31)
    ["city"]=>
    string(6) "london"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["movie_id"]=>
    int(34)
    ["city"]=>
    string(6) "berlin"
  }
}
```

Second array ($array2):

```
  array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(3)
        ["movie_id"]=>
        int(31)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(4)
        ["movie_id"]=>
        int(34)
      }
    }
```

How can i loop through the second array ($array2) use that movie_id to look through the first array, and insert the city, where the movie_id matches?

Im finding this very confusing?

hopefully i would end up with the 2nd array including an extra key with the city where the movie_id matches the first one?

Thank you!

Comment: can you alter the original arrays, it would be esier

Comment: A small hint: show us the desired result.

Comment: A foreach loop will do the trick.

Comment: Take it step-by-step, find the movie-id, iterate the inner arrays of array1 and compare the movie-ids etc. Once you've got some code and have a specific problem - post it here. SO is not made for other people to do your work - it's for other people to help you do you job!

Comment: @Dagon: no cant alter the original arrays, as they are coming from different outputs.

Comment: @Jari, though i explained that, but i see what you mean. i will display that in future SO questions.

Comment: @alfasin: I really didn't mean for other people to do the work for me. I was struggling to figure out the approach - your suggestion combined with the answer below, did help me on my way. I agree I could have phrased the question better. So sorry. Don't have to be rude though. Man, sometimes SO is intense. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something similar?

```
 <?php

   foreach($array2 as $key=>$value){

        if($key=='movie_id' && $value==$array1[$key]){
           $array2['city']= $array1['city'];
        }

   }


   print_r($array2);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The first condition wasn't necessary in my case, But the logic was the same. Thank you.